# accessing client's x509 certificate from within twisted web WSGI app

Tags: python, flask, openssl, twisted

I have set up a twisted + flask https server that also does certificate-based client authentication by following the documentation at the Twisted site [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html#tls-server-with-client-authentication-via-client-certificate-verification).  So far, so good.

In addition to authenticating the client using a certificate, the application code within the flask app needs the user name (which is present in the client x509 certificate) in order to do its job. I couldn't find an easy way to access this information. The information (based on the documentation) seems to be in the pyopenssl X509Name object at the time it does authentication, and I need the identity at the flask layer every time I process a request from that client.

The request object flask is getting did not seem to have this information (unless I read it wrong), so I assume I need to modify some options at the Twisted level to send them through to flask.  I also need to somehow get them out of the OpenSSL layer.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: using `HTTPChannel.allHeadersReceived` instead of `Protocol.dataReceived` for support of chunked requests.

You can use HTTP headers to store connection information: set them up in `HTTPChannel.allHeadersReceived` method and retrieve from `flask.request.headers`, e.g.:

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.http import HTTPChannel
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource

from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask('app')

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return 'User ID: %s' % request.headers['X-User-Id']

class MyHTTPChannel(HTTPChannel):
  def allHeadersReceived(self):
    user_id = 'my_user_id'
    req = self.requests[-1]
    req.requestHeaders.addRawHeader('X-User-Id', user_id)
    HTTPChannel.allHeadersReceived(self)

class MySite(Site):
  protocol = MyHTTPChannel

application = service.Application('myapplication')
service = service.IServiceCollection(application)

http_resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), app)
http_site = MySite(http_resource)
internet.TCPServer(8008, http_site).setServiceParent(service)
```

I'm not familiar with using client certificates in twisted. I assume you can retrieve its information in `Protocol.transport`.

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm concerned that this <code>data_received</code> implementation assumes we are not splitting a single request into multiple <code>data_received</code> calls. Is this a valid assumption?

Comment: @orm Yes, you're right, I didn't think about it. More correct way is to override `HTTPChannel.allHeadersReceived`. I updated my code example.